# Extract elements from a matrix based on the row and column indices with Armadillo

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, armadillo

In R, I could extract matrix elements based on their indices as follow

```
> m <- matrix(1:6, nrow = 3)
> m
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    2    5
[3,]    3    6
> row_index <- c(1, 2)
> col_index <- c(2, 2)
> m[cbind(row_index, col_index)]
[1] 4 5
```

Is there a native way to do this is Armadillo / Rcpp::Armadillo? The best I could do is a custom function that uses the row and column indices to calculate the element index (see below). I'm mostly worried that custom function won't perform as well.

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector Rsubmatrix(arma::uvec rowInd, arma::uvec colInd, arma::mat m) {
  arma::uvec ind = (colInd - 1) * m.n_rows + (rowInd - 1);
  arma::vec ret = m.elem(ind);
  return wrap(ret);
}

/*** R
Rsubmatrix(row_index, col_index, m)
/
```

Comment: Can you just the `.at()` member function.

Comment: `.at(n)` requires the element index. My question is if there's a native armadillo way that takes row_index and col_index as inputs.

Comment: From [here](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#element_access) it looks like both `.at(` and `operator(` both take up to three element accessors (i, j, k)

Comment: `(i, j, k)` are scalars. My inputs are vectors.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#submat):

```
X.submat( vector_of_row_indices, vector_of_column_indices )
```

but that seems to only return matrix blocks. For non-simply-connected regions, I think your solution is the best, but you don't really need a function,

```
m.elem((colInd - 1) * m.n_rows + (rowInd - 1));
```

returns the vector without any problem. For clarity you could define a function to deal with the row+col to indices conversion,

```
inline arma::uvec arr2ind(arma::uvec c, arma::uvec r, int nrow) 
{ 
  return c * nrow + r;
}
// m.elem(arr2ind(colInd - 1, rowInd - 1, m.n_rows));
```

Comment: I tried this. `.submat()` actually attracts all rows and columns that appear in the index. Try this:
`// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix test(arma::mat m, arma::uvec v1, arma::uvec v2) {
  arma::mat ret = m.submat(v1, v2);
  return wrap(ret);
}

/*** R
m <- matrix(1:6, nrow = 3)
test(m, c(0, 2), c(0, 1))
*/`

Comment: your question wasn't very specific. For non-contiguous elements, I think your solution would be the standard approach (but you may want to pass references, to avoid copying large objects)

Comment: I didn't want to say "non-contiguous" in the question because that's what the docs says about your solution. Hence I expected your solution to get non-contiguous elements as well, but it doesn't.

Comment: Is using: 

`test(m, c(0, 1), c(1)) ` that bad? @Heisenberg

Comment: @Coatless my indices contain multiple rows and columns though, not just `c(1)` for col_index.

Comment: You should give an example with a disconnected set of indices, that would greatly clarify the question.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this...

In particular, you can subset by `rowInd` and `colInd` through writing your own loop to use the `.(i,j)` subset operator. Otherwise, the only other option is the solution that you proposed to start the question off...

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// Optimized OP method
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec Rsubmatrix(const arma::mat& m, const arma::uvec& rowInd, const arma::uvec& colInd) {
  return  m.elem((colInd - 1) * m.n_rows + (rowInd - 1));
}

// Proposed Alternative
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::rowvec get_elements(const arma::mat& m, const arma::uvec& rowInd, const arma::uvec& colInd){

  unsigned int n = rowInd.n_elem;

  arma::rowvec out(n);

  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    out(i) = m(rowInd[i]-1,colInd[i]-1);
  }

  return out;
}
```

Where:

```
m <- matrix(1:6, nrow = 3) 

row_index <- c(1, 2)
col_index <- c(2, 2)

m[cbind(row_index, col_index)]
```

Gives:

```
[1] 4 5
```

And we have:

```
get_elements(m, row_index, col_index)
```

Giving:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    4    5
```

**Edit**

Microbenchmark:

```
microbenchmark(Rsubmatrix(m, row_index, col_index), get_elements(m, row_index, col_index), times = 1e4)
```

Gives:

```
Unit: microseconds
                                  expr   min    lq     mean median    uq      max neval
   Rsubmatrix(m, row_index, col_index) 2.836 3.111 4.129051  3.281 3.502 5016.652 10000
 get_elements(m, row_index, col_index) 2.699 2.947 3.436844  3.115 3.335  716.742 10000
```

The methods are both close time wise. Note that the later should be better as it avoids having two separate loops (1. to calculate & 2. to subset) and an additional temporary vector created to store the results.

### Edit

Per armadillo `7.200.0` release, the `sub2ind()` function has received the ability to take matrix notation. This function takes a matrix subscript via a `2 x n` matrix, where `n` denotes the number of elements to subset, and converts them into element notation.

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::rowvec matrix_locs(arma::mat M, arma::umat locs) {

    arma::uvec eids = sub2ind( size(M), locs ); // Obtain Element IDs
    arma::vec v  = M.elem( eids );              // Values of the Elements

    return v.t();                               // Transpose to mimic R
}
```

Calling in *R*:

```
cpp_locs <- locs - 1       # Shift indices from R to C++

(cpp_locs <- t(cpp_locs))  # Transpose matrix for 2 x n form

matrix_locs(M, cpp_locs)   # Subset the matrix
```

Comment: I would probably do some benchmarking to see which is faster. But coming from R, is my instinct that loop is more expensive warranted here?

Comment: @Heisenberg the initial benchmark has this method being slightly faster (microseconds) for the reasons I stated above. You probably should try it on a larger matrix though.

Comment: @Heisenberg see the above edit for using the newly implemented vectorized version of `sub2ind()`.